# DAX query to find unique value based on the condition on the value of another column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I Need some help with DAX query,

I have a source table like this one below,

[image: Source Table]

Need a code in DAX to remove all the rows whose status changed from failure to success from the table and keep only rows that have the status as success and return the filtered table like below,

[image: Filtered Table]

Comment: It's not clear how to determine which row should be removed. explain how you can verify if status chage from failure to success. In your example we can see that KEY1 change from Success to Failure (based on row order). Is there some additional column like timestamp or so?

Comment: yes. there is an additional Column called timestamp. From Time to time status will change. Goal here is to find all the rows whose status is Failure and if the same key exists which status as success, we need to remove that row whose status is failure from the table .